# How to create an RDD by selecting specific data from an existing RDD where output should of RDD[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, string-formatting, rdd

I have scenario to capture some data (not all) from an existing `RDD` and then pass it to other `Scala class` for actual operations. Lets see with example data(empnum, empname, emplocation, empsal) in a text file.

```
11,John,Paris,1000
12,Daniel,UK,3000
```

first step, I create an `RDD` with `RDD[String]` by below code,

```
val empRDD = spark
  .sparkContext
  .textFile("empInfo.txt")
```

So, my requirement is to create another `RDD` with empnum, empname, emplocation (again with `RDD[String]`).
For that I have tried below code hence I am getting `RDD[String, String, String]`.

```
val empReqRDD = empRDD
  .map(a=> a.split(","))
  .map(x=> (x(0), x(1), x(2)))
```

I have tried with `Slice` also, it gives me `RDD[Array(String)]`.
My required RDD should be of `RDD[String]` to pass to required Scala class to do some operations.

The expected output should be,

```
11,John,Paris
12,Daniel,UK
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve?

Comment: Can you try concatenating the String and return in your second Map which will return a Single string. Or you can use a Tuple 3.

Comment: Can you click the button "Comment add something useful for this Post" if you found this useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this

```
val empReqRDD = empRDD
  .map(a=> a.split(","))
  .map(x=> (x(0), x(1), x(2)))

val rddString = empReqRDD.map({case(id,name,city) => "%s,%s,%s".format(id,name,city)})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial implementation, the second map is putting the array elements into a 3-tuple, hence the RDD[(String, String, String)].

One way to accomplish your objective is to change the second map to construct a string like so:

```
empRDD
  .map(a=> a.split(","))
  .map(x => s"${x(0)},${x(1)},${x(2)}")
```

Alternatively, and a bit more concise, you could do it by taking the first 3 elements of the array and using the mkString method:

```
empRDD.map(_.split(',').take(3).mkString(","))
```

Probably overkill for this use-case, but you could also use a regex to extract the values:

```
val r = "([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*).*".r
empRDD.map { case r(id, name, city) => s"$id,$name,$city" }
```